# NoMethodError: undefined method `confirm!' for #<User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rake

I am trying to create an app using rails app composer tool. I am using `Devise` with `confirmable`. I am getting the error

```
rake db:seed
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `confirm!' for #<User:0xa0b26ec>
```

during the installation process.

Already the `user.rb` file has `:confirmable`

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

I am not able to do `rake db:seed`.

Comment: whats the DEVISE version you are using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `#confirm!` method has been removed.

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/26e22d8e953184b38a87f3a9b935db32258637d5

You have to use an older version or, what's better switch to the `#confirm` method.

Answer (score 6):

`Devise 4.2.0` has the **`confirm!` method depricated**, you have to **use `confirm` instead**.

**4.2.0 - 2016-07-01**

**removals:-**

```
Remove the deprecated Devise::ParameterSanitizer API from Devise 3. Please use the #permit and #sanitize methods over #for.

Remove the deprecated OmniAuth URL helpers. Use the fully qualified helpers (user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path) over the scope based helpers ( user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)).

Remove the Devise.bcrypt method, use Devise::Encryptor.digest instead.

Remove the Devise::Models::Confirmable#confirm! method, use confirm instead.

Remove the Devise::Models::Recoverable#reset_password! method, use reset_password instead.

Remove the Devise::Models::Recoverable#after_password_reset method.
```

From this,

**`Remove the Devise::Models::Confirmable#confirm! method, use confirm instead.`**

[Here is the refference](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: You can accept my answer if it helped you in the right way? If you wish to do.